# Syntax form PDO

Tags: php, html5, pdo

I was able to run the form to update the data of the user profile, for the moment is in a rough version, but I know that can be improved.

I post what I did, I hope you could help me to improve the code that definitely is unclear and with defects.

```
//form update
if ((isset($_POST['submit'])) || (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['gender'] ))) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET email=?, location=?, gender=? WHERE memberID = 1");
    $stmt->execute(array($email, $loc, $gender));
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
}
```

And,

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">        
    <label class="control-label">Location</label>   
    <input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['location'] ?>" />       
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
    <input type="text" name="gender" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['gender'] ?>" />
    </div>

<div class="margiv-top-10">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Update" >
<a href="account.php" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Front-end

I would remove the form's `action=""` attribute and any of the closing slashes in of your `input` tags, assuming you're using HTML5.

Instead of `<?php echo $_SESSION['email'] ?>`, you could do `<?= $_SESSION['email']; ?>`, etc.

I'd advise you to make a habit of always ending with a semicolon, even when it's not necessary.

## Back-end

Here's what I would do:

- Remove the comment, since it doesn't provide any value.
- Remove the intermediate variables, since there is no need for them.
- Remove storing the `rowCount()` (unless you're using it somewhere).
- Rewrite the if-expression.

Regarding the following expression:

```
(isset($_POST['submit'])) || (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['gender']))
```

Evaluating to true if `$_POST['submit']` is set **or** `$_POST['email']`, `$_POST['location']`, `$_POST['gender']` are all set. Not very safe, assuming you require every field to be filled based on looking at how your query is built.

I would just end up with the following code and if you wanted to do some specific things in a scenario where one of the fields has not been filled you can just add an `else` to the if statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['gender'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE members SET email = ?, location = ?, gender = ? WHERE memberID = 1");
    $stmt->execute([$_POST['email'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['gender']]);
}
```

---

You might find my answer a bit sloppy since I haven't answered any questions for a long time, but hopefully you find it to be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The update works fine, only that in the input value is not shown to date.

For example, if I update the field "Location", is updated correctly in the database but is not shown in the input field:

<input type="text" name="location" class="form-control" value="<?= $_SESSION['location']; ?>" />

How can I do? Perhaps it would be appropriate to create a class that taps the user data directly from the database?

Comment: @Marco Really, you should head over to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) for an answer on this question. CodeReview only handles working code. But, with the same way you populated the session with the user data beforehand should you fix this issue.